# Can't access all KeyStore aliases on USB Token

Tags: java, digital-signature, keystore, signing, pkcs#11

I used to access the certificate chain for PDF signing on a USB token with this code:

```
this._keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
this._keyStore.load(null, myPassword);
Enumeration<String> aliases = this._keyStore.aliases();
while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
    String nextElement = (String) aliases.nextElement();
    System.out.println("Enumeration element : "+nextElement);
try
{
    this._privateKey = (PrivateKey) this._keyStore.getKey(nextElement, pass);
    this._certificatesChain = (X509Certificate[]) this._keyStore.getCertificateChain(nextElement);
    if (this._certificatesChain.length == 0) 
    {
        //Let's try another
        continue;
    }
    if (this._certificatesChain[0].getKeyUsage()[1]) 
    {
        //I want to use this
        break;
    }
}
catch (Exception e){continue;}
```

I have been provided with a new USB token that won't work with this. It seems that using PKCS11 will just read one of the two certificates on the Token, which is not the one I am supposed to use for signing.

The best solution I came up with is using "Windows-MY" in the Keystore.getInstance() call, which can access all the certificates (even those that didn't come from the Token, but let's cross fingers). 
The BIG drawback of this is that doing so creates two PIN prompts for the whole signing process : the first time is the prompt I coded to ask the user for the PIN; the second time is when I try to sign - this time, with a Windows-style prompt.

Is there a way to either access all certificates with a PKCS11 Keystore instance, or avoid the Windows prompt?

Comment: Is it a standard usb storage key, or a cryptographic device ? In the second case, Pins are normal for security issues.

Comment: It's an USB signature token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I considered removing the post because there was a mistake somewhere else in my code, but I am leaving it here should anyone need it:

the problem was that the dll that I had been using to read the certificates (incryptoki2.dll) didnt work anymore with new keys from the same manufacturer. Switched to bit4ipki.dll and now I can read the certificates.

Comment: Windows-MY Gets all, but how you managed to not open two times the password prompt?